# launchd: Confusion on the sematics of bootstrap/bootout for controlling services on macOS

Tags: macos, service, launchd

I've read the following manual pages on launchd: `launchctl`, `launchd`, and `launchd.plist`.

However, nothing is really said in these manual pages regarding what the `launchctl boostrap` and `launchctl bootout` (sub)commands actually do (see below). Is it to be inferred from their names?

Futhermore, I cannot find information in the man pages, regarding what user/group the service (agent/daemon) runs as. However, `launchd.plist` mentions `UserName`/`GroupName` for controlling the user/group for the system domain. So, what user are per-user services in `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` run as?

Finally, I would expect I need to `bootstrap`/`load` my `daemon`'s .plist, but after putting the .plist in `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, it was automatically loaded (run) at system boot. Indeed, `RunAtLoad=true`, but what's the purpose of `bootstrap`, if services run anyway?

`man launchctl`:

```
 bootstrap | bootout domain-target [service-path service-path2 ...] | service-target
          Bootstraps or removes domains and services. When service arguments are present, bootstraps and correspondingly removes their definitions into the domain.  Services may be specified as a series of
          paths or a service identifier.  Paths may point to XPC service bundles, launchd.plist(5) s, or a directories containing a collection of either. If there were one or more errors while bootstrapping or
          removing a collection of services, the problematic paths will be printed with the errors that occurred.

          If no paths or service target are specified, these commands can either bootstrap or remove a domain specified as a domain target. Some domains will implicitly bootstrap pre-defined paths as part of
          their creation.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bootstrap` and `bootout` can be used to load and unload services *without* rebooting or logging in and out.  They can be useful if you need to temporarily stop a service to do some task and then start it up again without requiring a reboot of the system.

`/Library/LaunchDaemons` run as root by default.  You can use the `UserName` and `GroupName` keys to control the configuration of daemons.

`/Library/LaunchAgents` run as the currently logged in user (these run for every user).

`~/Library/LaunchAgents` run as that specific user.

For further reading:

- [Apple's "Daemons and Services Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html)
- `man launchd.plist`
- [launchd.info](https://www.launchd.info/) ***warning: outdated***, but still a useful basic tutorial for how launchd generally works.  Does not contain info on bootstrap/bootout.  Uses commands now deprecated and labeled "legacy".

Comment: By loading, only the services that specifies RunOnLoad will run immediately, right?

Comment: @Shuzheng I added some references in my answer for you.  As you your `RunOnLoad` question: it does not depend just on `RunOnLoad`, when you bootstrap it immediately loads the .plist and could run for several "when to run" type keys, for instance "StartInterval".

Comment: thanks, I've read the "Daemons and Services Programming Guide" myself. However, I cannot find any documentation on the `bootstrap` and `bootout` (sub)commands  of `launchctl`, can you? Only `man launchctl` defines `bootstrap` like "this command bootstraps...", which is not very helpful.

Comment: @Shuzheng no, there is nothing I have found beyond `man launchctl`, however I understand `bootstrap` to be equivalent to what the system does when it reads the special directories for .plist files at boot.  The `boot*` commands replaced the `*load` commands and function similarly except they are more verbose in how you declare your service, presumably to avoid ambiguities when loading and unloading services.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: Not more, thank you. I wish they had written, "`bootstrap` is the new equivalent of `load`" - that could have spared me from some confusion. Also, that loading is not the same as running. Loading just means to load the plist file and then wait until some key triggers the service to run (the actual service binary is then loaded into memory). Correct?

Comment: @Shuzheng - loading means parse the .plist. If the .plist is configured to run, it will run.  It all depends on what you put in your .plist, hence `man launchd.plist` is required reading.

Comment: Do you know if bootstrap is the same as load with respect to reboot? I.e. can one expect that an agent from /Library/LaunchAgents will be automatically loaded after reboot once bootstrapped?

Comment: @Kentzo - You do not need to run bootstrap or load commands to expect an agent to load at boot.  You just need to put the .plist file in /Library/LaunchAgents with correct ownership & permissions (refer to documentation).

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what might prevent an item from loading (locations, permission and ownership are correct).

Comment: @Kentzo - Go to https://www.launchd.info/ and click "Troubleshooting" in the nav bar.